# Cant splice array value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an insert and remove value in array. If a value is NOT EXISTED then insert if EXISTED remove it. But I have a simple condition to check whether the selected values are greater than 3. If greater than 3 dont add in the array and make a simple notification.

My problem is I can't remove the value if it is already existed.
Here's my simple code:

```
var limit = 3;
var findValue;
var ids = [];

function findIfExist(selected) {
    var findValue = jQuery.inArray(selected, ids);
    console.log(findValue);
    if(findValue >= 0) {
        ids.splice(selected, 1);
    } else {
        ids.push(selected);
    }
}

$('input[name="services[]"]').on('change', function(evt) {
    var count = $('input[name="services[]"]:checked').length;
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if(count > 3) {
        bootbox.alert({
            title: 'Oops',
            message: 'Only 3 services are allowed from the registration',
            size: 'small'
        });
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        findIfExist(selected);
    } else {
        findIfExist(selected);  
    }
    console.log(ids);
});
```

Sample output is a simple array with IDs

Can you spot where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) uses the index of the element to remove, not the element itself.

```
ids.splice(selected, 1);
```

Here, you're passing the element to the `splice()`. Use the index `findValue`.

```
ids.splice(findValue, 1);
```

Comment: @Jerielle Welcome :)